# Combining forecast from ARMA models

Tags: forecasting, standard-deviation, mean, arma

I have three ARMA(p,q) models for the variable X and using each model I produce forecasts for 12 months ahead. Note that in all three models the residual is normally distributed.

Now if I want to produce an ***average forecast*** and a ***standard deviation*** for the period $T+12$ using the forecasts from the three ARMA(p,q) models, should I be doing the following:

$$
\mu_{avg,T+12} = \frac{\mu_{model1, T+12}+ \mu_{model2, T+12}+\mu_{model3, T+12}}{3}
$$

$$
\sigma_{avg,T+12} = \sqrt{\sigma^{2}_{model1, T+12} +\sigma^{2}_{model2, T+12}+\sigma^{2}_{model3, T+12} }
$$

If not, how do I go about it?

Comment: No. The three forecasts will be highly correlated, so your variance is incorrect.

Comment: @RobHyndman Good point, I missed that. So how do I go about it?

Comment: Is your standard deviation meant to be the standard deviation of the average, or the sum?

Comment: You need to estimate the covariances. Also, as @Glen_b points out, you need to divide by 3 for the mean.

Comment: @Glen_b the standard deviation is meant to be the standard deviation of the average.

Comment: @RobHyndman How do I use the covariances to find the standard deviation of the average? If you could point out a formula that would be great.

Comment: fahmy, For the average, you need to divide the standard deviation of a sum of $k$ terms by $\sqrt{k}$. For the variance of a sum of correlated terms, see Wikipedia, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables).